# Angular2-text-ticker-directive not working in ionic 2 project

Tags: ionic2, angular2-directives

I am trying to implement the Angular2-text-ticker-directiv from [here](https://github.com/NateMay/Angular2-text-ticker-directive), but it not works. I got the div, and the div is empty, no scrolling text.

For test I added the example code to my project for test.

```
<ion-avatar item-left>
    <span class="story-username">{{getUsername()}}</span>
    <ion-icon name="icon-mapporia-edit" role="img" class="icon icon-ios ion-ios-icon-mapporia-edit story-edit" aria-label="icon mapporia-edit" ng-reflect-name="icon-mapporia-edit"></ion-icon>
    <p class="story-location">{{story.location}}</p>
    <div class="tickerContainer myStyles">
        <div ticker [trigger]="'auto'" [text]="'A statically-typed, long string'" [speed]="50" [padding-right]="40" [size]="20"></div>
    </div>
    <p class="story-time">{{calculatePostedTime()}}</p>
    <rating [(ngModel)]="story.ratingAvarege" readOnly="true" max="5" emptyStarIconName="star-outline" halfStarIconName="star-half" starIconName="star" nullable="false"></rating>
    <p class="story-subject">{{story.subject}}</p>
</ion-avatar>
<li class="thumnail-list" *ngFor="let image of story.images">
    <img-loader [src]="image" [spinner]="true" class="thumnails" alt="Story Image" id="story-image">
    </img-loader>
</li>
```

I added the `<div id="ghost"></div>` before calling my custom directive (shown up):

```
<div class="profileDetails">
    <story-summary *ngFor="let story of myStories" [story]="story" (click)="readStory(story)" class="story"></story-summary>   
</div>
```

I also included the given css:

```
.tickerContainer {
        overflow-x: hidden;
        overflow-y: scroll;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }

    #ghost {
        display: inline-block;
        height: 0;
        position: absolute;
    }

    .myStyles {
        background: #eee;
        color: blue;
        border: 1px solid #ddd;
        max-width: 200px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
```

If anyone with experience to help me solve this problem. 
thnx

I found a bug.
Please correct the following method as given:

```
getTextWidth(): number {
        let t = this.r.createElement( document.getElementById('ghost'), 'div' );

        // this.r.setText( t, this.text ); // not working, oddly
        t.innerHTML = this.text; // quick fix

        this.r.setElementStyle( t, 'font-size', this.size + 'px');
        let w = t.offsetWidth;
        t.innerHTML = '';
        return w;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same issue as yours. The ticker directive in the link you provided contains some errors.

Older-

```typescript
createTickerNode( self: any , text: string ): any {
    self = this.r.createElement( this.el.nativeElement, 'span' );
    this.r.setElementStyle( self, 'padding-right', this.paddingRight + 'px');
    this.r.setElementStyle( self, 'font-size', this.size + 'px');
    this.r.setText( self, text );
    return self;
}
```

Newer -

```typescript
createTickerNode( self: any , text: string ): any {
    self = this.r.createElement( this.el.nativeElement, 'span' );
    this.r.setElementStyle( self, 'padding-right', this.paddingRight + 'px');
    this.r.setElementStyle( self, 'font-size', this.size + 'px');

    // this.r.setText( self, text ); // not working, oddly
    self.innerHTML = this.text; // quick fix
    return self;
}
```

Replace your older code in ticker directive with the new one.
Hope it will help resolving your issue. If yes then please mark my answer as correct :)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @g00glen00b, I have edited my answer